# ReactNative Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: react-native

I execute command `react-native run-ios`.

Will show fail to load bundle.

I've tried to ....

1. Delete the node_modules folder - `rm -rf node_modules` && `npm install`
2. Reset packager cache - `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache`
3. Clear watchman watches - `watchman watch-del-all`

But not solved question.

Please look the error Screenshot.

Thank you.

[Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZM9A.png)

```
React Native Environment Info:
System:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
  CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7360U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  Memory: 4.97 GB / 16.00 GB
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 10.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  npm: 6.1.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 11.4, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11.4, watchOS 4.3
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4819257
  Xcode: 9.4.1/9F2000 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: ^16.3.1 => 16.3.1 
  react-native: ^0.56.0 => 0.56.0 
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "projactname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    "key-mirror": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "pretty-format": "^22.4.3",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-ble-manager": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.18.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-carousel-pager": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.12",
    "react-native-image-gallery": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-payments": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^5.0.6",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.6",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-unique-id": "^1.0.4",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-axios-middleware": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-observable": "^0.18.0",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "^5.1.1",
    "rn-splash-screen": "^5.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.71.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Update:

I've tried removing node_modules and move the project to Desktop.

Still same question.

Metro Bundler - lanuchPackager.command

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/index.js
    at createDescriptor (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:162:11)
    at items.map (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:87:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:87:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:79:10)
    at presets (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:61:19)
    at presets (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:51:25)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:308:26)
    at /Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:271:7
```

Comment: try removing node_modules, move the file into new location and then npm install

Comment: I try to it. but is not working. please look my new post. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. I've changed in **.babelrc**:

```
"presets": ["react-native-stage-0"]
```

to

```
"presets": ["react-native"]
```

Answer (score 0):

clean the Metro Bundler:  rm -fr $TMPDIR/metro* I am not sure where exactly are metro files located in windows but search and remove them. Also you can try to change your project name and bump up the project version in package.json

```
"name": "projactname",
"version": "0.0.1",
```

If you still have the same issue after all the steps you took so far, most likely the problem in somewhere in your app logic. Test that by creating some sort of hello world program in your App.js instead of loading the project files. Repeat that down in the tree of you project files until you locate the issue.